# How to know current time from internet from command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, ntp

How to know current time from internet from command line in Linux?

For example, with `ntpq` program?

Note: not from computer or operating system clock, but from internet?

Note: I don't want to CHANGE or to SYNC time. Just KNOW it.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79112/how-do-i-set-time-and-date-from-the-internet

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you use bash the following line will do the job

```
$ cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13

56525 13-08-21 23:07:09 50 0 0  55.6 UTC(NIST) *
```

It leverages the built-in network capabilites¹ of the bash shell. If you use a POSIX shell or any other shell you can use e.g. [netcat.](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/)

```
$ nc time.nist.gov 13

56525 13-08-21 23:07:09 50 0 0  55.6 UTC(NIST) *
```

Both commands query the timer server on TCP port 13 of the [National Institute of Standards and Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology) and output the received data on stdout.

¹*EDIT:* From [the Bash man page:](http://man.cx/bash) Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections, as described in the following table:

> `/dev/tcp/host/port`
>      If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an integer port number or 
>        service name, bash attempts to open a TCP connection to the corresponding socket.
>
> `/dev/udp/host/port`
>        If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an integer port number or
>      service name, bash attempts to open a UDP connection to the corresponding socket.

Comment: Nice, +1. Could you expand a bit on how this works? Or, since I seem to be missing a large chunk of bash knowledge here, give me a name to look this behavior up with? What is the `</dev/tcp/` format?

Comment: The two minor drawbacks I see with this approach is that different time zones are not easily supported and no format can be specified in a straight-forward way. To remedy that situation, one could use the [time api](http://www.timeapi.org/). For example, to query the actual time for central Europe in a more human legible way, one simply invokes: `curl -G --data-urlencode "format=%D-%T\n" http://www.timeapi.org/cet/now?`

Comment: Not sure if time.nist.gov has any rate limiting or is overloaded but I get varying results with this host.

Comment: Huh, TIL bash has network capabilities. That's kinda neat! Thanks for sharing this answer.

Answer (score 25):

There are several [NTP services](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ntp) available per distro.

If you would like to do a **one time clocksync**:

```
date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"
```

**Set system time to hardware Real-Time-Clock**

```
hwclock -r --utc
hwclock -w --utc
hwclock -r --utc
```

*(Note: this happens to work well with Google because they have severs all over)*

---

**If you would like to just see what time Google's nearest server sends:**

```
date -d "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep ^Date: | sed 's/Date: //g')"
```

Answer (score 23):

The [`ntpdate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpdate) command can do this with the `-q` flag:

```
$ ntpdate -q 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
server 88.191.120.99, stratum 3, offset -0.015076, delay 0.06604
server 88.191.235.218, stratum 2, offset -0.000676, delay 0.06592
server 188.165.240.21, stratum 3, offset 0.001191, delay 0.07005
server 91.121.34.166, stratum 2, offset 0.000565, delay 0.06998
22 Aug 00:56:21 ntpdate[31373]: adjust time server 88.191.235.218 offset -0.000676 sec
```

From `man ntpdate`:

```
   -q     Query only - don't set the clock.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also obtain the time over the Internet using either HTTP using [HTP](https://www.rkeene.org/oss/htp/) which is available on many systems as `htpdate` which usually only has accuracy to the nearest second, or you can obtain it using TLS using [`tlsdate`](https://github.com/ioerror/tlsdate) which can provide better accuracy:

```
tlsdate -nV google.com
```

Also since `ntpdate` is [being deprecated](https://www.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.8-series/ntpdate/) you can use [`sntp`](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/sntp.html) (it's installed by default on MacOS and comes as part of the ntp distributions) to obtain the date much more accurately:

```
sntp pool.ntp.org
```